# Where to find Ubuntu One logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, troubleshooting, ubuntu-10.04, logging

Ubuntu one does not synchronize files since I upgraded from 9.10 to 10.04. The preferences panel keeps showing "Synchronization in progress...", but files are not downloaded from the repository. It does not show any error message.

Where do I find the programm logs, where I can investigate my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
.cache/ubuntuone/log
```

Not sure why it's so hard to find, but this [thread on log size](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/435137) reveals the location.

Comment: Thanks, this is the right answer... unfortunately, I couldn't find the reason for the bug in the logs, so I desinstalled and reinstalled completely ubuntu one.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Bugs , looks like this should be ".cache/ubuntuone/log"